# How do I read a CSV that has blank columns caused by extra separators at the end of each row?

Tags: r, csv

Suppose I have the following CSV, which has 6 columns containing data:

```
METB;Metropolis Municipal Bonds   ;100;BOND   ;MAIN     ;2020-01-23;
PFM ;Precision Food Manufacturing ;121;EQUITY ;MAIN     ;2020-12-30;
NLT ;Northern Light and Telegraph ;47 ;EQUITY ;MAIN     ;2020-03-21;
PAE ;Peninsula Aeronautical Inc   ;75 ;EQUITY ;SECONDARY;2020-11-11;
```

Note that the CSV file contains an extra separator at the end of each row (i.e. a trailing `;`), which causes R to treat my CSV as having 7 columns instead of 6.

I am currently reading the CSV using:

```
df <- read.csv(
    './data.csv',
    header=FALSE,
    sep=';',
    strip.white=TRUE,
    col.names=c('ticker',
                'name',
                'price',
                'type',
                'board',
                'date',
                'unused.column'),  # <- ATTENTION.
    colClasses=c(ticker='character',
                 name='character',
                 date='Date',
                 unused.column='NULL'))  # <- ATTENTION.
```

This works correctly for doing all of these at the same time:

- reading the CSV,
- giving the column their correct names (instead of `V1`, `V2`, etc.),
- giving the column their correct classes (e.g. `character`, `Date`, etc.),
- ignoring the last column

However, I feel that my solution is dirty because I had to explicitly give the blank column a name (i.e. `unused.column`) in order to delete it using `"NULL"` in `colClasses`. If my CSV contains multiple blank columns at the end of each row (e.g. `;;;;;;`), the method I am currently using will start to become impractical.

What is a better way to ignore the last column when reading a CSV, while giving each column their correct header names, and giving each column their correct classes?

Comment: I actually like your current method.  Do you really expect to have so many unused columns in your input CSV?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I am expecting many unused columns in my input CSV. I would prefer not to have to name them `unused.column.1`, `unused.column.2`, `unused.column.3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table`'s `fread` where you can specify how many columns you want to read :

```
data.table::fread('./data.csv', select = 1:6, 
              col.names=c('ticker','name','price','type','board','date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `vroom`

```
library(vroom)
vroom('./data.csv', col_select = c(ticker, name, price, type, board, date))
```